# Else Without If Error in VBA, New Line after Then and Indentation seem ok

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have read all questions about If error in VBA before posting this.
There is a new line after *Then*, the indentation seems ok, yet I keep on getting the missing If error. I have tried leaving only *Else* in the last statement but then Debug says there is a missing *Then*. No matter what I do I keep on getting it. I am definitely missing something but I cannot find it.
Could someone please advise?

```
        If lstShapeSelect = False Then
            MsgBox "Nothing selected"
    
    
        ElseIf lstShapeSelect = "Circle" Then
            For Each Shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    
            Shp_Cntr = Shp.Left + Shp.Width / 2
            Shp_Mid = Shp.Top + Shp.Height / 2
            
            
                            '        Circle
            Set New_Shape = myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeOval, Left:=Shp_Cntr - ((Shp.Width * Ratio) / 2), Top:=Shp_Mid - ((Shp.Width * Ratio) / 2), Width:=Shp.Width * Ratio, Height:=Shp.Width * Ratio)
            New_Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 100)
            New_Shape.Line.Weight = 0.75
            New_Shape.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            New_Shape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            New_Shape.Name = "Circle"
        
        
        
        ElseIf lstShapeSelect = "Fake Circle" Then
            For Each Shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    
            Shp_Cntr = Shp.Left + Shp.Width / 2
            Shp_Mid = Shp.Top + Shp.Height / 2
    
    
    '         Rounded Rectangle As Circle
            Set New_Shape = myDocument.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRoundedRectangle, Left:=Shp_Cntr - ((Shp.Width * Ratio) / 2), Top:=Shp_Mid - ((Shp.Width * Ratio) / 2), Width:=Shp.Width * Ratio, Height:=Shp.Width * Ratio)
            New_Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(240, 240, 240)
            New_Shape.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            New_Shape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            New_Shape.Adjustments(1) = (1 / (New_Shape.Height + New_Shape.Width)) * RadiusFactorCircle
            New_Shape.Name = "Fake Circle"
                
                
        End If
```

Comment: Your `For Each` statements are missing a `Next` before each `ElseIf` - If you are trying to put the `Next` after your `If` statement completes, that's not going to work. Either move the `For...Each` outside of the `If`, or include a `Next` inside each set of code that is using a `For Each`

Comment: Thank you, now it's working. Just to understand the reason why, is VBA interpreting the missing "Next" as if the previous statement was not closed, hence the following "If" is missing?

Comment: More or less, yes. It thinks you want a new `If` statement inside the loop because you never closed the loop, and you cannot start an `If` statement with `ElseIf`.

Comment: And keep in mind that indenting it properly is only for you, the programmer, to keep it structured in a way that is organized. It does not affect execution.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, from previous readings I understood that the indentation could be a cause of misinterpretation by VBA. So only the new line is mandatory.

Comment: *So only the new line is mandatory.* No you can use colons instead of CRLF. So your whole program can be on one line. Also lines can be split over several by putting `_CRLF` where you want the line broken. `msgbox _` `"Hi there"`.

Comment: I agree, but those alternatives you are mentioning would be just formal ways to break/unbreak the lines for the  programmer to better read, while for VBA they are treated, respectively, as New Line or Same Line, wouldn't they? The syntax would not actually change, it would only be for the reader.

Comment: @Bradipo Yes they are the same to VBA. There are 5 passes made.  The Physical Line Grammar,  The Logical Line Grammar,  The Lexical Token Grammar,  The Conditional Compilation Grammar, then  The Syntactic Grammar. This is the rules for writing your own VBA compiler - which you can download here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/d5418146-0bd2-45eb-9c7a-fd9502722c74. It's main use to me is to work how things are auto converted, known as let coercion.